# Are there conditions that insure the total (Frechet) derivative is self-adjoint?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Is there a set of conditions that guarantee that the total or Frechet derivative of a function is self-adjoint?  Specifically, given a function $f:X\rightarrow X$, we know that $f^\prime(x)\in \mathscr{L}(X)$.  I'd like a set of conditions that guarantee that $f^\prime(x)=f^\prime(x)^*$.  Under some mild conditions, we know that when $f(x)=\nabla g(x)$ for some $g\in C^2(X)$ we have that $f^\prime(x)=\nabla^2 g(x)$ is self-adjoint.  I'm curious if there are other situations that are easy to identify where we know this is true as well.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it happens only when $f(x) = \nabla g(x)$.

Let me sketch a proof. Assume $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is an inner product on $X$ and $f:X\to X$ is a $C^1$-function satisfying
$$ \langle Df(x).h, k \rangle = \langle h, Df(x).k \rangle\,,$$
for all $x, h, k \in X$. Then we define
$$ g(x) := \int_0^1 \langle f(tx), x\rangle \,dt\,.$$
Its gradient is
\begin{align*}
\langle \nabla g(x), h \rangle &= \int_0^1 \langle Df(tx).th, x \rangle + \langle f(tx), h \rangle \,dt \\
&= \int_0^1 \langle h, t Df(tx).x \rangle + \langle h, f(tx) \rangle \,dt \\
&= \int_0^1 \partial_t \left( \langle h, t f(tx) \rangle \right) \,dt \\
&= \langle h, f(x) \rangle\,.
\end{align*}
This shows that $f(x)$ is of the form $f(x) = \nabla g(x)$ with a $C^2$-function $g$.